# Problem to display taxonomies terms in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

i created a custom post type (call bookmaker_post_type) with more custom taxonomies asociated but i have problem to display the terms selected of each  taxonomy. I tried to use the function the_terms `<td><?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'countrie'); ?></td>` in post single but not show nothing. I also tried to insert the function in the loop but nothing. Where i wrong?

taxonomy code

```
// Add new taxonomy Countries, make it hierarchical (like categories)
$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Countries', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Countrie', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Countries', 'textdomain' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Countries', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Countrie', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Countrie:', 'textdomain' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Countrie', 'textdomain' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Countrie', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Countrie', 'textdomain' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Countrie Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Countrie', 'textdomain' ),
);
 
$args = array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'countrie' ),
);
 
register_taxonomy( 'countrie', array( 'bookmaker' ), $args );
     
    unset( $args );
    unset( $labels );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$post` isn't declared. So you can't use `$post->ID`. You have to either declare it using `global $post;` or simply use `get_the_ID()`.

```
the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'countrie' );
```

On a side note, plural is `countries` singular is `country` not `countrie` ... but that's just English grammar.

---

### In a loop

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ):
  $i = 0;
  while( have_posts() ): the_post();
    $i++;
    if ( $i > 1 )
      echo '<hr>';
    the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'countrie' );
    the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
  endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

---

### Learn more

- `get_the_ID()` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/
- `the_terms()` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_terms/

Comment: Thank you for the reply i solved it with the following code but still it doesn't print me the taxonomy permalink :( ...                         `function show_all_terms($taxonomy){
    $taxonomy_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
    foreach($taxonomy_terms as $term){
        $terms[] = $term->name;
    }
    if(!empty($terms)) {
        echo join(", ", $terms);
    }
    else{
        echo "No ".$taxonomy."associated with this ".get_post_type();
    }
}`